# Creating hashes for passwords

Tags: php, passwords, hash

I am creating a custom CMS and have built a login system and was wandering how vulnerable hashing the passwords this way would be compared to just using the md5 php function like this:

```
<?php $token = md5($salt . $password . $pepper); ?>
```

Most people just add a salt but adding pepper just makes sense if your going to add salt :)

Here is how I am doing it

```
<?php $token = hash_hmac('sha512', $salt . $password . $pepper, $key); ?>
```

The $key would be a value in the database that is unique to each user.
The $salt and the $pepper are randomly generated strings.
The $password is the password of course.

Added on 07/24/09

Thanks for all your responses. Does anyone have an examples of how they do a hash script for creating passwords to store in a database?

Comment: it is in the first paragraph

... how vulnerable hashing the passwords this way would be compared to just using the md5 php function like this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111494/are-hashed-and-salted-passwords-secure-against-dictionary-attacks)

Make sure you read this:

http://www.matasano.com/log/958/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-secure-password-schemes/

And this:

[bcrypt is obsolete](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-05-09-scrypt-key-derivation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is using a stronger hash.

I don't see you opening yourself to any extra vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is not suitable for any cryptographic purpose, use SHA-1 or preferable SHA-256.

http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: Yeah... that's probably why he's using SHA-512.

Comment: Yeah I got turned on to the SHA-512 because of the length of the encryption